# Hide Year Attribute in Date Module

Tags: datetime

I have created a date field that prints out the time for a list of courses offered at a local employment office. I have used a custom input format (h:i A) for the user to input their course start/end time. When the new course listing is created the date field displays 0000-4:30PM to 6:30PM. I assumed the 0000 is representing the year attribute which is selected by default and I am unaware how to change it’s default setting.

I have also included a screen captures below:

[image]

[image]

I’m still rather new to Drupal so I’m not sure what step I am missing.

**System Information:**

- Drupal 7
- Bartik 7.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intrigued by your question, I found the same issue with trying to use a date field to store a time as the date field stores a Unix Timestamp.

A Drupal 7 project called [timefield](http://drupal.org/project/timefield) allows you to store a time which has no relation to a date, even has duration, and display configuration. I have not used it in a live environment, but looks like a solution for you.

Comment: I looked into the timefield module as possible solution but with it's current stages in dev/alpha it's a drawback.

Comment: Agreed, but take a look, test, contribute issues and suggestions to the community. Some things never leave Beta, but are great, just not 100%.

Comment: You were right timefield does solve my issue. I'm going to take you advice and keep working with this module to help improve it and get it off the ground.